# DataStore<T>.data doesn't emit values in tests

Tags: android, android-jetpack, kotlin-flow, android-jetpack-datastore

I'm writing a test for a simple class that reads & writes to Datastore directly to store data locally on device, but when I try to verify that the data I saved matches what I read, the test fails with the message

> "app.cash.turbine.TurbineAssertionError: No value produced"

the code for my simple class is:

```kotlin
import androidx.datastore.core.DataStore
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.catch
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.map
import javax.inject.Inject

class Example @Inject constructor(
    private val favAStore: DataStore<ProtoA>
) {
    val aList = favAStore.data
        .catch {
            emit(listOf(A("", 0)))
        }
        .map {
            it.listOfA.map {
                A(foo = it.foo, bar = it.bar)
            }
        }

    suspend fun addAToFavourites(a: A) {
            favAStore.updateData {
                val protoA = a.toProtoA()
                if (protoA !in it.listOfA) {
                    it.toBuilder().addProtoA(protoA).build()
                } else {
                    it
                }
            }
    }
     ....
}

data class A(
    val foo: String,
    val bar: Int
)
```

and my test setup is:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleTest {

    @get:Rule
    var hiltRule = HiltAndroidRule(this)

    private val testScope = TestScope()
    private val context: Context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()

    private val favAStore: DataStore<ProtoA> = DataStoreFactory.create(
        serializer = FavouriteASerializer,
        scope = testScope,
        produceFile = { context.dataStoreFile("fav_a_test.pb")}
    )

    private lateinit var example: Example

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        example = Example(favAStore)
    }
}
```

when trying to write a simple test like this using [Turbine](https://github.com/cashapp/turbine), it fails with the message above:

```
    @Test
    fun test() = testScope.runTest {
        favAStore.updateData { it.toBuilder().clear().build() }

        example.addAToFavourites(A("Hello", 9))

        example.aList.test {
            expectThat(awaitItem()).isEqualTo(listOf(A("Hello", 9)))
            awaitComplete()
        }
    }
```